# How can I hide the system keyboard and use my own custom keyboard when a TextField is focused in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use my own custom keyboard instead of the system keyboard, how to hide system keyboard when TexField is focused

I try

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the system keyboard try to use:

```
 CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTextInputService provides null,
    ) {
     BasicTextField()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested above can still be used before compose1.6.2, but cannot be used in later versions. In later versions, LocalTextInputService will be deprecated. There is currently no way to disable the soft keyboard in one step.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35706160)